# Can I pass a block to it_behaves_like in Rails RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

Providing that I have a shared example:

```
shared_examples 'success' do
  let(:params) { key: "value" }

  it "returns data" do 
    post "/api/users", params: params

    expect(response.status).to eq (201)
  end
end
```

When I use this shared example with `it_behaves_like`, can I pass a block to it to extends the list of expected?

For example, I write it like this:

```
  it_behaves_like "success" do 
    expect(response['id]).to eq(1)
  end
```

in hope of rspec to compile it like this:

```
  it "returns data" do 
    post "/api/users", params: params

    expect(response.status).to eq (201)
    expect(response['id]).to eq(1)
  end
```

The above code is obviously not working as I wanted, but I want to know how to write it so that RSpec can understand it like my expected outcome above. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could separate it into a [shared context](https://rspec.info/features/3-12/rspec-core/example-groups/shared-context/) which performs the API request and a [shared example](https://rspec.info/features/3-12/rspec-core/example-groups/shared-examples/) which checks the status code, e.g.:

```
shared_context 'request' do
  before do
    post '/api/users', params: params
  end
end

shared_examples 'success' do
  it 'returns with 201 status code' do
    expect(response.status).to eq (201)
  end
end
```

These can then be combined:

```
describe 'a successful request' do
  include_context 'request' do
    let(:params) { { key: 'value' } }
  end

  it_behaves_like 'success'

  it 'returns data' do
    expect(response['id']).to eq(1)
  end
end
```